# Grunt exec running a node command in background

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, gruntjs, grunt-exec

I'm trying to run grunt with a js script. The script start up a server that should be listening all the time in background. To it I'm using grunt and grunt-exec, and my exec.js is like that

```
start: {
        cmd: function () {
            var start = 'node server.js &';
            console.info('Starting');
            return start;
        }
    }
```

When I run `grunt exec:start` the process finish but the server is not running.

Same command without '`&`' works but it's not the wanted.

I've tried to move the command to a bash but the result is the same, the server is never started when the character '`&`' is added, neither in the *.sh* nor in the *grunt-exec* command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it changing the command:

```
var start = "nohup node server.js";
```

I.t seems run in background properly.